# Template for Login Page in html

Tags: templates, authentication

I have been developing a java application. Now I have decided to convert this into a web application. Can someone suggest me good links for the template of the login page. Not able to get a good one so far. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about these:

Some basic ones:

http://sprawsm.com/uni-form/

http://www.roscripts.com/uploads/CSS_forms/forms.html

https://appleid.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MyAppleId.woa/161/wa/directToSignIn?wosid=bttym9oFSL4JPtRLZYF9rg&localang=en_US

The creative ones:

http://creativedesignmagazine.com/30-awesome-login-page-designs-for-inspiration.html

Comment: Hey, how about posting the answer as correct,I guess its's customary. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Everyone's taste is different. You can [use mine](http://demo.dertermin.com/manage/), I have nothing against it.

Comment: Hey do u mind giving the source file for this code. Well thanks in advance :)